# Importing data from CSV file into MYSQL

Tags: mysql, windows

I am trying to load data into a database table (MYSQL 8.0.28) in my Windows 11 pc through `load data local infile` command.

I have gone through the syntax (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html), some problems with trying to import string as date, enabling the import process in the server with the server variable `local_infile` and the connection variable `OPT_LOCAL_INFILE`.

Now when I try to run the script I get:

> Error Code: 2. File 'covidDeath.csv' not found (OS errno 2 - No such file or directory)

I want to use relative addresses, and I have copied the file into the directory of the server executable but it is the same.

Where should I put the data files in order to reference them with a relative address?

Comment: As your Error says that "covidDeath.csv" is not found", it indicates that either you're not providing the correct path of the file OR name of file is different. 
Can you please check it once, and get back here if you still faced any issue.

Comment: The file exists, I have downloaded it and I am trying to reference it like this: load data local infile 'covidDeath.csv'. I have tried to put it (the csv file) in the same folder as the script and in the same folder of the .exe of the server, same error both times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both files are in same folder then try using the following command:

```
load data local infile './covidDeath.csv'
```

Let me know if you still face any issue.

Comment: should it be the same folder as the script with the "load data local infile" statement, or in the same folder of the .exe of the mysql server, maybe the same folder as workbench?

Comment: It turned out that it was the workbench .exe folder!